# Python using try to reduce timeout wait

Tags: python, exception, telnet, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

I am using exscripts module which has a call  conn.connect('IP address').
It tries to open a telnet session to that IP.
It will generate an error after connection times out. 
The timeout exception is set somewhere in the code of the module or it would be what the default for telnet is. (not sure)

This timeout time is too long and slowing down the script if 1 device is not reachable. Is there something we can do with the try except here ? Like

Try for 3 secs:
 then process the code
except:
 print " timed out"

Comment: I don't know `exscripts`, but... you could try a `threading.Timer` that fires in 3 seconds and closes the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
conn = Telnet(timeout=3)
```

I dont know whether `timeout` in seconds. If microseconds, try `3000`

Answer (score 1):

We changed the API. Mike Pennington only recently introduced the new [connect_timeout parameter](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/pull/76) for that specific use case.

New solution (current master, latest release on pypi 2.1.451):

```
conn = Telnet(connect_timeout=3)
```

We changed the API because you usually don't want to wait for unreachable devices, but want to wait for commands to finish (some take a little longer).